# Use phpcassa for cassandra with yiiframework

Tags: php, pdo, yii, cassandra, phpcassa

Does anyone know how to use `phpcassa` for `cassandra` with `Yiiframework`?

I've tried `Cassandra PDO`. It works very well, but I happened to like the way `phpcassa` works. Especially the support for most `cassandra` features.

I don't know but I found `phpcassa` much easier to use.

Any suggestions?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Yii in particular, but after glancing at it, I suspect you won't be able to use most of the Yii ORM-like features directly, whether it's though phpcassa or the PDO driver.  Certainly it could work for some cases, but in general, your data in Cassandra is not modeled around objects, it's modeled around queries.  Your goal is to lay out your data in such a way that you can answer queries that you have planned for very efficiently.  Because Yii is object-oriented, there's a fundamental mismatch in how it expects you to interact with the database.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I perfectly understand how Yii works and also how the storage model (and design approach) of Cassandra differs from that of relational databases; therefore when choosing this solution, I had already completely ruled out the possibility of using features like Active Records, Active Forms (maybe), e.t.c. Phpcassa would be quite sufficient for the work I want to do, the only problem I have is "How to integrate it into Yii". Thank you :-)

Comment: Ah, good to hear.  Since I'm not familiar with Yii, I can't provide guidance for integrating phpcassa.  I would suggest looking for how others have used other non-relational databases with Yii; the patterns would probably be similar here.

Answer (score 1):

I've written an Yii extension today for cassandra-cql3, hope this might help others searching for an yii wrapper for cassandra CQL3

https://github.com/masumsoft/yii-cassandra-cql3